Create P12 certificates for Elastic using GitHub Workflows
This is more a general question than a problem.
Is it possible, in a github workflow, to create P12 certificates to be used for an elastic cluster?
These are the steps for the flow:

Have GitHub workflow with a self-hosted runner
Have a CA certificate (stored in Azure Key Vault) to use to create the P12 certificates
Fetch CA from Azure Key Vault, and mount the CA to a folder on the self-hosted runner
Use a public docker container for elastic
Mount the CA over to the docker container
Create P12 certificates using the mounted CA
Move P12 certificates over to the self-hosted runner
Send P12 certificates as extra-vars to an ansible playbook

I was thinking something like this, but not too sure if it will work. Don't know how to test workflows locally.

Mount the /certs folder with the CA over to the docker container
Mount the instances.yml file over to the docker container
Create P12 certificates


docker run --rm \
            -v ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs \
            -v ${{ inputs.instances_file_path }}/instances.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instances.yml \
            docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.2 \
            elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-stack-ca.p12 \
            --in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instances.yml \
            --out /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/certs.zip -ca-pass "$pwd" --pass "$pwd"


Where instances.yml file contains node name and ip address of the nodes in the cluster. The file is structured like this:
instances:
   - name: elasticnode1
   ip:
     - 0.0.0.0
   - name: elasticnode2
   ip:
     - 0.0.0.0


The $pwd attribute is the attribute used to create the CA certificate, and will be used to create the P12 certificates for each node specified in the instances.yml file.
